# GroupingBy with List as a result

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

We have the following:

```
public List<Balance> mapToBalancesWithSumAmounts(List<MonthlyBalancedBooking> entries) {
    return entries
      .stream()
      .collect(
        groupingBy(
          MonthlyBalancedBooking::getValidFor,
          summingDouble(MonthlyBalancedBooking::getAmount)
        )
      )
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(localDateDoubleEntry -> new Balance(localDateDoubleEntry.getValue(), localDateDoubleEntry.getKey()))
      .collect(toList());
  }
```

Is there a possibility to avoid the second stream() path in the code, so the result of the groupingBy() should be a list in our case. We need a possibility to pass the map()-function to collect or groupingBy is that possible in Java 8?

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: Java 8 :(
But solutions for more modern Java versions could be posted too for persons with same problem.

Comment: @ChristianWiedehöft That's not even possible, with imperative (`for`) style either. Unless the `Balance` objects are mutable and can move around a unique key somehow. I would suggest giving it a try both ways. And what is the reason for moving to a single call to `stream`?

Comment: You can create your own collector doing the merging in the first pass.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is just using `toMap()` collector with merge function like this:

```
List<Balance> balances = new ArrayList<>(entries.stream()
       .collect(toMap(MonthlyBalancedBooking::getValidFor, m -> new Balance(m.getAmount(),
                                              m.getValidFor()),Balance::merge)).values());
```

I supposed for `Balance` class these properties:

```
class Balance {
   private Double value;
   private Integer key;

   public Balance merge(Balance b) {
     this.value += b.getValue();
     return this;
   }
}
```

Comment: I did give this a thought, hence the comment. The problem here is the key that you're choosing for the map and then deciding over how to merge. The objects that you're creating with the intermediate `map` operation might just be flawed.

Comment: Very elegant solution. The only thing I would change is moving the `merge` method out of POJO. Having a static utility method for this purpose is much more flexible approach. One may have no access to the source code of `Balance` class.

Comment: You would also have to add the `Balance::getKey` which didn't exist in the questions code. Or you get rid of the `map` operation and stay closer to the question's code: `entries.stream() .collect(toMap(MonthlyBalancedBooking::getValidFor, m -> new Balance(m.getAmount(), m.getValidFor()), Balance::merge))`

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't be possible since the value that you are looking for as you map to the `Balance` objects could only be evaluated once all the entries of the `MonthlyBalancedBooking` list are iterated.

```
new Balance(localDateDoubleEntry.getValue(), localDateDoubleEntry.getKey())
```

An alternate way though with moving the stream though within a single terminal operation could be by using `collectingAndThen` as:

```
public List<Balance> mapToBalancesWithSumAmounts(List<MonthlyBalancedBooking> entries) {
    return entries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(MonthlyBalancedBooking::getValidFor,
                            Collectors.summingDouble(MonthlyBalancedBooking::getAmount)),
                    map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                            .map(entry -> new Balance(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: We are looking for a solution without need to open second stream().
If it is possible ;)

Comment: This only moves the creation of a second stream, but the OP wants to avoid that second stream entirely.

Comment: @ChristianWiedehöft That wouldn't really be possible. See the update.